# What is the difference between the underscore in code and in the interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I was playing around with the `_` underscore in the Python interpreter and wanted to try if it has the same behavior in code. I have used the underscore in code as a 'Don't care'-variable, like this:

```
_, a = someFunction()
```

And in the interpreter to get the last stored value, like this:

```
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> a = _
>>> a
4
```

Now I tried to execute the following example code:

```
for i in range(5):
    2 + 1
    a = _

print (a)
```

In the interpreter as well as written in a Python script and ran using `python underscore.py`.
With the behavior in mind that the `_` underscore will save the last stored value, because this it is not formatted as a 'Don't care'-variable, the expected outcome would be `2 + 1 = 3`, making `3` the last stored value, which is then saved into the `a` variable with `a = _`.

The outcome of the interpreter was the following:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     2 + 1
...     a = _
...
3
3
3
3
3
>>> print(a)
3
```

This outcome works as expected while the outcome of the same code saved in a Python script and ran using `python underscore.py`, resulted in a name error:

```
C:\Users\..\Python files>python underscore.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "underscore.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = _
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

When reading the error, it sounds logic that the `_` variable is not defined, but, while it probably has something to do with how Python runs a script, I was just wondering what the difference between these two cases is that makes the outcome result in a somewhat logic answer (when you've been using the interpreter like this for a while) vs a name error?

So don't get me wrong, I do know what the `_` symbol does in Python. What I'm asking is why the exact same code behaves differently in the interpreter then when run as a Python program in the terminal?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc

Comment: I can re-open if you think the dupe is wrong, but it seems like you do already understand the difference, so I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: @Chris_Rands I just want to know why the behavior of the `_` is different between Python code and the interpreter. The answer you posted is what the `_` in code means, and yes, I know what it does

Comment: Ok i re-opened but what are you asking them? About the internals of how the python interpreter is implemented? Or about the *rationale* for the different behaviour? Look up `sys.displayhook`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks for that reference, `sys.displayhook` explains exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: The special assignment to `_` only happens when you execute an *expression* in interactive mode.  That's not what's happening here - you're executing a *statement* (a `for` loop), which has no value to assign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone that finds it interesting, with the help of [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands) I found out that the Python interpreter stores the last used value using `sys.displayhook`, more on that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook).

`sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an expression entered in an **interactive** Python session. Meaning that it will only have this behavior in the interpreter and not in a Python script ran in the terminal.